# Выделение символов регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Проблема такая:
есть последовательность чисел например **9032292283**
Нужно сделать так: **(903) 22-9-22-83**
То есть искать последовательности одинаковых символов и добавлять символы "-";

Я думаю реализовать это за помощью **preg_replace**, но у меня возникли ряд вопросов:

1. как угадать количество нужных масок ? Так как последовательностей
   может быть и 2, и 3, или больше (a98**222**01**3355**68**44**)
2. возможно ли такое реализовать регулярными выражениями или пойти методом обработки строк ?
3. можете объяснять как работает "\1+" в моей регулярке ?

Код PHP:

```
$str = preg_replace('/([0-9])\1+/', '$1', 'a9032292283');
```

Comment: **1.** ничего не понятно из фразы. **2.** Реализовать скорее всего можно, если можно точно сформулировать словами принципы что именно брать, а что не брать. **3.** \1+ говорит что может быть 1 и более повторов той цифры, которую захватили первые скобки

Comment: ну нужно выделять последовательности чисел типа 222 и добавлять к ним дефис -222-, то есть делать замену 222 на -222- в строчке.

Comment: 3. а как навивается такая штука "\1+"  что бы я смог почитать ?

Comment: [Обратная ссылка](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.back-references.php).

Comment: обратная связь. И ваша регулярка очень похожа на правду, нужны вторые скобки `(([0-9])\2+)`

Comment: @w3lifer спасибо.

Comment: @mike спасибо и Вам. Помогло. А скажите как можно еще исключить такой вариант "2233" - получается -22--33- а нужно -22-33- ?

Comment: А вот это уже проблема для php и preg_replace. из быстрых решений в голову приходит только после обработки заменить все -- на -, отдельным str_replace

Comment: Все решили )
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для точной расстановки ровно по 1 знаку `-` обрамляющих повторяющиеся цифры, без повторов знаков минус на стыке повторяющихся групп:

```
$str='9032292283';
print preg_replace('/(?=(?!\G)(\d)\1+)|((\d)\3+)/', '$2-',$str);
```

Тест: [101regex.com](https://regex101.com/r/oI2wZ4/1)

Страшное выражение до разделителя ИЛИ (`|`) захватывает 0 символов после которых присутствуют повторяющиеся цифры (отрицание `\G` обеспечивает, что бы условие не сработало в середине строки повторяющихся цифр). При этом $2 остается пустым и замена просто вставляет `-` перед повторяющийся группой. Выражение после ИЛИ отвечает за вставку знака минус после повторяющийся группы (захватывая всю группу как $2).

Comment: Ваш вариант поставил как верный. Спасибо за потраченное время и маленький ликбез )

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $st='9032292283';
  $prefix=substr($st,0,3);
  preg_match_all('/(\d)\1*/',substr($st,3),$res);
  $phone=implode('-',$res[0]);
  echo "({$prefix}) $phone";
```

Comment: @MaksDevda А ничего что этот вариант ставит тире еще между 8 и 3 в приведенной строке. В постановке задачи такого не было

Comment: Да проверил все верно. Сразу даже не заметил.